# Change selectedIndex on a UITabBarController without making it change the current view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` with 4 tabs, the first two being "Program" and "Workout".

Whilst on the first tab's view, the user can select the program they wish to perform, and then tap "Perform Workout" which will take them to the workout screen.

My aim is to show the workout screen as part of the same navigation controller as the program select, however I want to update the `UITabBarController` to reflect the fact that we're now on the workout screen.

The problem is that if I call

```
UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController*)self.navigationController.parentViewController;
[tabController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

This opens the `WorkoutViewController` inside a new `UINavigationController`, instead of using the old one.  I realise that the two `UINavigationController` problem is happening because of my `storyboard`, but if I don't have two separate `UINavigationControllers`, the TabView doesn't stay on top all the time (it disappears after the first push).

[image: My storyboard]

How can I update the `selectedIndex` on my `UITabBarController` WITHOUT forcing it to load the new `UINavigationController`?

Comment: What is the problem if you have two navigation controller

Comment: When I call [tabController setSelectedIndex:1], the "workout" screen opens inside its own navigation controller (i.e. there is no back button to go back to the program select screen).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should disconnect your Workout controller and push this controller using storybord id not from Program  controller but change the selected index of tab push this controller to second navigation cotroller

Comment: That sounds great.  I understand adding the workout to the first navigationcontroller with a performSegue, but how would I change the selected tab index without pushing it to the second navigationController (like is happening at the moment?)

Comment: I have updated my answer but you need delegation for exchanging the data in between, In my opinion using the Storybord like this scenario do not fit best then xib. :)